# Type error in string shuffle function

Tags: haskell, types

I have tried to create my own string shuffle function:

```
import System.Random

-- usage case: my_shuffle "something" ""

my_shuffle :: [Char] -> [Char] -> [Char]
my_shuffle [] result = result
my_shuffle s result = do 
    pos <- randomRIO (1, length s)
    my_shuffle (remove_char pos) (result ++ (get_char pos))

get_char :: [Char] -> Int -> Char
get_char s pos  = s !! (pos - 1)

remove_char :: [Char] -> Int -> [Char]
remove_char s pos = take (pos - 1) s ++ drop pos s
```

It returns the error message:

```
substitution_cipher.hs:8:16:
    Couldn't match expected type `[t0]' with actual type `IO a0'
    In the return type of a call of `randomRIO'
    In a stmt of a 'do' expression: pos <- randomRIO (1, length s)
    In the expression:
      do { pos <- randomRIO (1, length s);
           my_shuffle (remove_char pos) (result ++ (get_char pos)) }
```

As I see it is related to IO, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: If you're unsure about a type, it's often convenient to omit the type signature, load it into GHCi, and do a `:t <thing>` to make Haskell tell you the type.  Then you can add that type signature to the source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you aren't passing the string argument to`remove_char` and `get_char`. Also, you need to turn the result of `get_char` into a list in order to use `++`. The recursive call to `my_shuffle` should look like:

```
my_shuffle (remove_char s pos) (result ++ [get_char s pos])
```

Secondly, you need to use the IO monad for `randomIO`, so the signature of `my_shuffle` should be:

```
my_shuffle :: [Char] -> [Char] -> IO [Char]
```

Then finally you need to use `return` in the base case (since you need to return an `IO  [Char]`):

```
my_shuffle [] result = return result
```

With fixes applied:

```
import System.Random

my_shuffle :: [Char] -> [Char] -> IO [Char]
my_shuffle [] result = return result
my_shuffle s result = do
     pos <- randomRIO (1, length s)
     my_shuffle (remove_char s pos) (result ++ [get_char s pos])

get_char :: [Char] -> Int -> Char
get_char s pos  = s !! (pos - 1)

remove_char :: [Char] -> Int -> [Char]
remove_char s pos = take (pos - 1) s ++ drop pos s
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detail answer. But I have another one question: is there any way to return [Char] from my_shuffle, instead of IO [Char].  I want to use the result as common string: f a b = a ++ b ; f "some" (my_shuffle "some" "")

Comment: @demas: No. Pure functions have to return the same result for the same input, which `my_shuffle` obviously doesn't, so it has to be in `IO` to indicate that it's non-determininstic. To use it with `f`, you can for example write `f "some" <$> my_shuffle "some" ""` which will again be in `IO`. The other option is to make it deterministic by taking the random number generator as an input, but then you have to worry about passing that around.

Comment: @demas - you are using `randomRIO` which means you have to return an `IO [Char]`.