# zip [Char] and IO [Char]

Tags: haskell

I have a [Char]:

```
*Main> let message = "something"
```

and I have shuffled string (full code you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123133/type-error-in-string-shuffle-function)):

```
*Main> let key = shuffle message

*Main> message
"something"

*Main> :t message
message :: [Char]

*Main> key 
"goeimntsh"

*Main> :t key
key :: IO [Char]
```

Now I need to create Data.Map from this two strings.  Something like:

```
Map.fromList(zip message key)
```

But I cannot even zip [Char] and IO [Char]:

```
*Main> zip message key
<interactive>:1:13:
    Couldn't match expected type `[b0]' with actual type `IO [Char]'
    In the second argument of `zip', namely `key'
    In the expression: zip message key
    In an equation for `it': it = zip message key
```

I understand that shuffle function doesn't return the same result for the same input. So it has to return IO [Char].

I understand that I cannot get Map.Map and I agree to get IO Map.Map. But I need to work with IO [Char] the same way as ordinary string.  How can I get it ?

Thanks.

**Updated:**

Thanks all of you for your explanation.  Some additional question:

*@KennyTM:*

I understood 'do'- notation, but I need a little time to get liftM :)
But there is one additional question right now:

```
*Main> let s = "abcdef"
*Main> let d = shuffle s
*Main> s
"abcdef"
*Main> d
"fedcba"
*Main> buildIOMap s d
fromList [('a','e'),('b','a'),('c','c'),('d','f'),('e','d'),('f','b')]
*Main> buildIOMap2 s d
fromList [('a','c'),('b','b'),('c','f'),('d','a'),('e','e'),('f','d')]
*Main> Map.fromList (zip "abcdef" "fedcba")
fromList [('a','f'),('b','e'),('c','d'),('d','c'),('e','b'),('f','a')]
```

'buildIOMap' is a do-notation; 'buildIOMap2' - is a liftM - realization.

Why I get different result in three cases ?

Comment: You could use the `do` notation and extract the `key` inside... Or just `liftM` the result of `zip`...

Comment: Sorry, I ma newbie in Haskell. Can you give me example, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could make an IO function for this. We use the `do` notation here as it is more friendly for beginners with background of imperative languages, but it is not the most compact way.

```
buildIOMap message key = do
    rawKey <- key                   -- unwrap an object inside the 'do' with '<-'
    let zipped = zip message rawKey -- Then 'zip' & 'Map.fromList' can be used 
    let map = Map.fromList zipped   --   normally.
    return map                      -- Finally we re-wrap the result into IO.
```

---

We could also solve this in a more functional way, which is to transform the function itself. Notice that expression `Map.fromList (zip message key)` fails only because `key` is an `IO [Char]` instead of a `[Char]`.

If we could transform the function `Map.fromList (zip message __)` from accepting a `[Char]` to an `IO [Char]` then it would also work. Such transformation is called *lifting*, when in Haskell [the `Control.Monad.liftM` function](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad.html#v%3aliftM) will do this:

```
liftM :: Monad m => (a -> r) -> (m a -> m r)
```

This will take a function with 1 pure argument and return 1 pure argument, and give out a function with 1 monadic argument and return 1 monadic argument.

Here our pure function is:

```
\x -> Map.fromList (zip message x)
```

So we can also write:

```
buildIOMap message = liftM (\x -> Map.fromList (zip message x))
```

<sub><sup>(Note: An even more compact way representing the above is `buildIOMap message = liftM $ Map.fromList . zip message`)</sup></sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answers.  I have updated my question - can you please explain some moments ?

Comment: @demas: [@hammar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13134053/224671)   has already answered you.

Comment: Thank you one more time - you really help me :)

Answer (score 4):

From the GHCi prompt, you just have to do

```
> key <- shuffle message
```

This runs the `IO` action on the right hand side and stores the result in `key`, which is now just a plain string.

```
> :t key
key :: [Char]
```

On the other hand, when you wrote

```
> let key = shuffle message
```

what you did was just naming the action, so you could for example run it multiple times and get different results:

```
> :t key
key :: IO [Char]
> key
"ntimshgoe"
> key
"gimhntoes"
```

The difference between evaluating a value and running an action is somewhat blurred in GHCi, since it lets you do both from the same prompt. However, you'll get a type error if you try to mix them the wrong way like with your `zip` example.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `key` is not a `[Char]` - it is a `IO [Char]` - i.e. an IO computation which will return a `[Char]`. Here's an example of how to use your shuffle function:

```
main = do let message = "something"
          key <- shuffle message
          -- now key is a [Char]
          let m = Data.Map.fromList (zip message key)
          print m -- ... or whatever
```

In a sense, the `<-` unwraps the `IO` from the `IO [Char]` and places the returned value into the variable to left of the `<-`.